# Mapping routes to layouts in Sinatra, help me clean this up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm a front end guy getting more and more into using sinatra. I'm building an app currently and am trying to find an elegant way to DRY up the routes in my myapp.rb file.

Currently I have these routes:

```
get '/' do
  haml :content 
end

get '/content' do
  haml :content, :layout => :empty
end

get '/show_layout' do
  haml :show_layout
end

get '/conversion' do
  haml :conversion, :layout => :empty
end

get '/optout' do
  haml :optout, :layout => false
end

get '/terms' do
  haml :terms, :layout => :empty
end
```

With regards to the templates, I know I can do something like this to combine them:

```
get '/:name' do
  haml params[:name].to_sym
end
```

But what about the layouts? There are only 2 layouts here, layout.haml and empty.haml (:layout, and :empty), 3 if you count :layout => false

Is this something that is best done using a hash? Something like:

```
layout_map = {
  "" => "",
  :content => "",
  :show_layout => "",
  :conversion => :empty,
  :optout => false,
  :terms => :empty    
}

get '/:name' do
  haml params[:name].to_sym, :layout => layout_map[:name]
end
```

Seems like its on the right track but I can't get it to work properly.

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It seems like a good question to me...

Comment: try to replace `layout_map[:name]` with `layout_map[params[:name].to_sym]`

Comment: @apneadiving unfortunately no dice, when I do that and try to visit /conversion I get this error "TypeError at /conversion
can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Comment: what is `"" => ""` supposed to mean?

Comment: EDIT: this is working for /conversion and /terms, but not for /content, /, or /show_layout  


"" => "" is supposed to mean, when trying to visit '/' the layout should be the default layout. Maybe I need to write "" => :layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help everyone. Ended up going with this as my solution due to some other requirements of the app.

```
get "/:base_route/" do
  haml :"#{params[:base_route]}/content", :layout => :"#{params[:base_route]}/layout"  
end

get "/:base_route/:name" do
  layout_map = {
    :landing => :layout,
    :content => :empty,
    :show_layout => :layout,
    :conversion => :empty,
    :terms => :empty    
  }        
  haml :"#{params[:base_route]}/#{params[:name]}", :layout => :"#{params[:base_route]}/#{layout_map[params[:name].to_sym]}"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your:

```
get '/:name' do
  haml params[:name].to_sym
end
```

plus a before route that will set your layout:

```
before '/:name' do
  layout_map = {
    :content => "",
    :show_layout => "",
    :conversion => :empty,
    :optout => false,
    :terms => :empty    
  }
  set :layout => layout_map[params[:name]]
end
```

This will set your layout according to `params[:name]` with every call. But be careful with `.sim`ming every route. If someone calls many 404s you create lots and lots of dead symbols which are not garbage collected and eventually will crash your app. Better do this:

```
get '/:name' do
  halt 404 unless File.exist?("views/#{params[:name]}.haml")
  time = File.stat("views/#{params[:name]}.haml").ctime
  last_modified(time)
  haml params[:name].intern
end
```

This will only create a symbol for `params[:name]` if there is a file with that name. So you're on the safe side because the symbol already exists.